# Can my Venezuelan girlfriend take connecting flights within the US to get home?

Tags: visas, usa, venezuelan-citizens

My girlfriend is from Venezuela and we are planning a trip from Europe to Venezuela later this year but the easiest and cheapest flights seem to stop in the U.S. Although I can get a holiday visa and ESTA to enter, what does she do? As it will be 2 connecting flights within the U.S and then on to Caracas.

Comment: Well, she will need some legal way to enter the US. Check if citizens from Venezuala can travel under the US visa waiver rules. If not, she will need a visa to travel through the US. So it may be cheaper that take an alternative connection that avoids transiting in the US. A good travel agent will help you with booking a reasonable connection if you cannot find a search engine that will allow you to avoid flights through the US.

Comment: She will need to get a U.S. transit visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to avoid US-based airlines. These will stop in the US as that would be their main transit hub.

If you stick with European airlines, you can avoid the US completely.

You did not mention from where in Europe, but as an example from UK you have [quite a few options](http://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/lond/ccs/150812/150815/airfares-from-london-to-caracas-in-august-2015.html?rtn=1&includePlusOneStops=true&browsePrice=622&age=2).

Comment: Sorry, we would be flying from Dublin Ireland, I know that there is flights that fly to UK/then Germany then over but over €500 in the difference in flights where as holiday visa and ESTA don't actually cost so much! So if I could get away with that it would be perfect but if not I'd have to suck it up and pay the higher option! 

Answer (score 3):

No. She will need to get a US visa for any connections in the US.

A handy tool for figuring these sort of things out can be found here: http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Comment: the problem I see with that site is it wants to know where you are visiting. the person in question is trying to go home, which is not exactly covered. the site is trying to figure out what visas/travel arrangements you need to visit your destination, not live there. or am I missing something?

Comment: In effect she will be visiting the US if transiting, hence the relevance.